# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'. android API 9

Tags: android

When i compile my app to API 19, compile is good, but if i compile app to API 9, i have Error:

```
Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/test/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/res/values-v11/values.xml
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
...
```

How i can fix it? I want compile this app for api 9
build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 9
...
minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 9
...
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Comment: Your compile and sdk version should both be as high as you've tested against (e.g. 19 in this case). The only thing that should be at API 9 is your minSdkVersion (if you're supporting Froyo).

Answer (score 3):

You are using `AppCompat` which mean you need to used its Light version not the native android non support Theme.

**sample:**

change this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```